# Updating an App Cloned with Parallel Space

Tags: updates, whatsapp-messenger

I just found that Parallel Space lets you clone apps, for example, you can have two Whatsapp accounts at the same time.

What happens when the app (Whatsapp in the example) is updated? Does the cloned version updates automatically or it remains with the previous version?

Comment: Both versions need to be separately updated. See  Christo Goodman app review

Comment: I use Xiaomi dual apps feature (inbuilt with the MIUI) and it updates the dual app if the main app is updated.

Answer (score 2):

The cloned  app doesn't get updated automatically. You will have to create the clone again after updating.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel Space is just a **container**, which is a virtual Android environment within the mobile device. The container has its own home screen, launcher, apps, and widgets. Apps and data inside the container are isolated from apps outside the container.

A container doesn't "clone" apps, it only separates virtually a device into two "spaces". I don't use Parallel Space, but I use MyKnox which is a container from Samsung. And when an app is updated, it is also updated in the container and vice versa. No need to update separately.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel Space will automatically update the cloned app whenever the original app is updated. I have been using it for over a year. For example, when I open Facebook and get the notification that the app has been updated, the next time I open the cloned Facebook app, I will also get an app update notification on it.

I had previously used another cloning app that actually copied the APK file to clone it, and it did not update automatically. I would have to manually do it each time. That's why I switched to Parallel Space.